# Satellite Video Remote Sensing data

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

Does anyone know of any satellite missions (open access or not) presently acquiring global Video Remote Sensing data?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "global Video"?  A video of the entire globe (impossible, we can see at most <50%; also, not very interesting as you won't see much changing in seconds, except at impossibly high resolutions), a satellite continuously taking a video such that it will cover the entire globe (still too much data to be feasible), or a satellite that can be commanded to take a video of a spot anywhere on the planet (which I seem to recall existing)? Also, what is video if not images with a very high repetition rate?

Answer (score 0):

Geosynchronous weather satellite remains stationary with respect to the rotating Earth and thus can record or transmit images of the entire hemisphere below continuously with their visible-light and infrared sensors (from Wikipedia). I think this one of them.